# how to hide and show with jquery if the page reload?

Tags: html, jquery

I have a `table` and some text where I get the data when I submit the `form`.

When I first open the page it shows an empty table. I want that when I open the page the table is hidden but when I submit the form the table will show.

In this code, section is the one div id and section two is the table and the section button is the submit button of the form. With this code when I land on the page the table and text are hidden but when I submit the page it refreshes and it comes back to a hidden state again and it will not let show the table

```
$("#section1").hide();
$("#section2").hide();

$("#sectionbutton").click(function () {
  $("#section1").show();
  $("#section2").show();
})
```

Comment: i think i get something maybe i have to work with cookies now on this senario

Comment: You need to manually store the state of those elements somewhere, as HTTP requests are stateless. I'd suggest using localStorage.